# how to quantile-discretize on spark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, feature-engineering, bigdata

i want to quantile-discretize RDD[Float] to 10 pieces without Spark.ML, so i need to calculate 10th-Percentile, 20th-Percentile...80th-Percentile,90th-Percentile

data-set is very big, can't collect to local!

have any efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already provided this capability is your are using Spark version > 2.0. You have to convert your RDD[Float] to a dataframe. Use `approxQuantile(String col, double[] probabilities, double relativeError)` from `DataFrameStatFunctions`. 
From the documentation is says:

> This method implements a variation of the Greenwald-Khanna algorithm
>   (with some speed optimizations). The algorithm was first present in
>   Space-efficient Online Computation of Quantile Summaries by Greenwald
>   and Khanna